# Excel: Convert MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: excel

We have a large sheet with expiration dates. Most are currently formatted MM/YYYY. Unforunately the new ones are MM/DD/YYYY. How can I add 01 (first day of the month) to the MM/YYYY formatted dates so they comply with MM/DD/YYYY?

Example:
Convert 05/2016 to 05/01/2016

Thanks!

Comment: Are the expiry dates (old and new format) actual date/time values or text?

Comment: @Jerry the function I put should work either way.

Comment: They are date/time formatted. I dont see how the downvote is warranted.

Comment: No my issue was that when formatted the day of the month did not exist. So i needed a way to manually insert it so the formatting would take properly. Ill check superuser next time prior to posting on either site.

Comment: @aensm The thing is, if it's a date/time value, you _only_ have to change the formatting via Ctrl+1 and you don't need anything more than that!

Comment: @pnuts If the dates are really strings that look like dates, formatting them to `mm/dd/yyyy` does not do anything. However, if they are actually dates, then reformatting a `mm/yyyy` date will automatically become `mm/01/yyyy`

Comment: Oh sorry, I see @Jerry already explained that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=DATE(YEAR(cell_with_date),MONTH(cell_with_date),1)
```